# How can I remove the "unlink relationship" either permanently, user based or amount of relationships?

Tags: customization, relationship, sugarcrm, sugarbean

On SugarCRM 7+ how can I remove the "unlink relationship" either permanently, user based or amount of relationships?

My problem is that I have two custom modules with a many-to-many relationship between them and I can't limit a user from editing, deleting or creating records on both modules since I actually want the users to be able to do those actions etc but at the same time I need to block unlinking of relationships either:

1. permanently
2. user based
3. based on the current amount of relationships

I've gone through a lot of google searching (about 7 hours total) but I couldn't find a tutorial or blog post about this type of customization for SugarCRM 7.1+ (I feel things changed a bit on subpanel customization on this version)

**also, is there a way to easily add a "created_datetime" and "deleted_datetime to the relationship itself?** I found a few "overkills" for such customization and my sugar skills are not that high to implement them.

Comment: Subpanel work very differently in SugarCRM 7.x. I've not done this sort of customization for 7.x yet so I'll subscribe here. I expect 7 is too new to get a lot of answers here, but I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I've decided to have extra modules making the relationship so then I have a related field on each of my current modules pointing to a module in the middle where I can customise fields anyway I want "and" I will block the related fields from modification based on user and if the field has been set already etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to have extra modules making the relationships so then I have a related field on each of my current modules pointing to a module in the middle where I can customise fields anyway I want "and" I will block the related fields from modification based on user and if the field has been set already etc.

This is an obvious solution but I wanted to have less modules for plain and simple OCD. Once I convinced my brain that not being able to customise the relationship with "control" fields was even worse for OCD than having more modules everything settled down!